# Поиск по SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Как правильно сделать такую штуку, что бы когда делаю запрос по таблице, допустим, цифру 3, не выводило 13. Или 2 - что бы поиск не выдавал поля , где есть 22. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, спасибо.  Сами числа записаны в поле помеченным типом `TEXT`, но в одной ячейке может быть, к примеру так `13, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22`

Использую такой запрос

```
 SELECT * FROM bus_station WHERE  bus_key_query LIKE '%2%';
```

Запрос выводит 2, 20, 22, а нужно получить только конкретный ответ 2.

Comment: Покажите проблемный запрос. Но одна проблема уже видна - если в поле нужно хранить числа, то почему тип у него текстовый?

Comment: я добавил запрос в вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перед использованием таких операторов как `LIKE` убедитесь что вы точно знаете как они работают. Если посмотреть в [документацию](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) (неожиданно) то можно найти такое:

> The LIKE operator does a pattern matching comparison. The operand to
>   the right of the LIKE operator contains the pattern and the left hand
>   operand contains the string to match against the pattern. A percent
>   symbol ("%") in the LIKE pattern matches any sequence of zero or more
>   characters in the string. An underscore ("_") in the LIKE pattern
>   matches any single character in the string. Any other character
>   matches itself or its lower/upper case equivalent (i.e.
>   case-insensitive matching).

Оператор `LIKE` использует в своей конструкции [регулярные выражения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), где поиск происходит по определеному паттерну. Вы же, в своем паттерне (`%2%`) говорите, что нужно найти число 2 с ЛЮБЫМ количеством символов до и также ЛЮБЫМ количеством после. Следуя из этого ваш паттерн должен просто выглядеть так:

```
SELECT * FROM bus_station WHERE  bus_key_query LIKE '2';
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто, не используйте `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM bus_station WHERE bus_key_query = 2;
```

Ну, и `bus_key_query` стоит сделать числовым полем.

Comment: Вот у меня в одном поле только одно число - 2. Тогда все работает, а во втором несколько через запятую 2, 4, 6, 12 - в этом случае не работает просто ничего не выдает в ответ)))

Comment: А значения через запятую - это денормализация данных и нарушение реляционных принципов. Так быть вообще не должно.

Comment: для этого я делал тип текст, но если значения ставлю INTEGER и через пробел , то тоже нет результата

Comment: Вообще не должно быть больше одного значения в одном поле.

Comment: Окей , это я понял, тип изначально текст, и я учусь делать по запросу выборку всех полей из таблицы в которых есть определенные слова, ну в моем случае пока что это просто цифры через запятую

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос, в тексте которого подробно опишите конкретную задачу, покажите DDL, пример данных и пример ожидаемого вывода.